# Vue 3 render function: how to inject `&nbsp;` as a bare HTML node

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a functional component and cannot figure how to inject `&nbsp;` between 2 spans as a bare HTML. Any ideas? The only solution I see atm is to render the whole stuff as `innerHTML`, but maybe there's some Vue way to do that?

```
export default function Price({ price, currency }, { slots }) {
    return h('div', { class: 'price_flex price_flex_bold' }, [
        h('span', { style: 'text-transform: none;' }, slots.default?.()),
        h('span', { innerHTML: '&nbsp;' }),
        h('span', { style: 'width: auto' }, formatter.format(price)),
        ' ',
        h('i', currencies[currency])
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Maybe `h({template: '<span />&nbsp;<span />'})`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a text node:

```
createTextVNode('\u00A0')
```

Answer (score -1):

The *createElement()* method allows you to create a new Vue element. In this case, we are using it to create a span element with the   character as its inner HTML.

```
<template>
  <div class="price_flex price_flex_bold">
    <span style="text-transform: none;">{{ slots.default?.() }}</span>
    <span>{{ createElement('span', { innerHTML: '&nbsp;' }) }}</span>
    <span style="width: auto;">{{ formatter.format(price) }}</span>
    {{ ' ' }}
    <i :class="currencies[currency]"></i>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { createElement } from 'vue';

export default {
  name: 'Price',
  props: {
    price: Number,
    currency: String,
  },
  slots: true,
  methods: {
    createElement(tag, options) {
      return this.$createElement(tag, options);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

or

The *v-html* directive allows you to render HTML code as a string. In this case, we are using it to render the **&nbsp** character.

```
<template>
  <div class="price_flex price_flex_bold">
    <span style="text-transform: none;">{{ slots.default?.() }}</span>
    <span v-html="'&nbsp;'"></span>
    <span style="width: auto;">{{ formatter.format(price) }}</span>
    {{ ' ' }}
    <i :class="currencies[currency]"></i>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Price',
  props: {
    price: Number,
    currency: String,
  },
  slots: true,
};
</script>
```

Comment: i don't need `&nbsp;` wrapped in `<span>`, that breaks the layout (i can't change HTML/СSS), i need `<span />&nbsp;<span />`

Comment: also I need a functional render only component, and `createElement` seems vue 2 specific